# wso2am No valid session found for user

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, openid-connect

I'm using wso2am 2.0.0 and have implemented a website to login with openId connect over wso2am. It works fine with the default user admin/admin, but when I use my new user created in the admin interface from carbon I got this error afer clicking "approve".

> INVALID REQUEST
>
> access_denied
>
> No valid session found for the
>   authenticated user andreapplication=testapp

How I created the new user:

- login with admin/admin
- click on the left under Identity -> Users and Roles -> Add
- Add new user: enter name and password -> finish

I've grant already all roles and permissons to the new user, but same error.

Comment: Any errors in wso2carbon.log?

Comment: No. Nothing at all.

Comment: Can you try to login in a private browser window?

Comment: Nice, that works! .. but why?

Comment: My suspect was this. https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-5210

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have 2 SPs for OIDC, and those have 2 different `Subject Claim URI` values in `Claim Configuration` section, this can happen. It's a [known issue](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-5210).